# C String garbled？

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h> //demo1
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char ida_chars[] =
    { 0x40, 0x35, 0x20, 0x56, 0x5D, 0x18, 0x22, 0x45, 0x17, 0x2F, 0x24, 0x6E, 0x62, 0x3C, 0x27, 0x54, 0x48, 0x6C, 0x24, 0x6E, 0x72, 0x3C, 0x32, 0x45, 0x5B,0 };
    char key[] = { 0x40, 0x35, 0x20, 0x56 };
    char key1[] = { "flag" };
    char key2[5] = { "&YA1" };
    char flag[25] = { "0" };
    int len = strlen(ida_chars);
    int len1 = strlen(key);
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        key[i] ^= key1[i];
    }

    printf("%s\n", key);
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
    {
        flag[j] = ida_chars[j] ^ key2[j % 4];

        
    printf("%c", flag[j]);
    }
//out1:&YA1?
//out2:獱]"E齰e_Defe€甬慚7T膯幥陼嶟乼
//<砚$Uべ                                  

    
}

#include <stdio.h>  //demo2
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char ida_chars[] =
    { 0x40, 0x35, 0x20, 0x56, 0x5D, 0x18, 0x22, 0x45, 0x17, 0x2F, 0x24, 0x6E, 0x62, 0x3C, 0x27, 0x54, 0x48, 0x6C, 0x24, 0x6E, 0x72, 0x3C, 0x32, 0x45, 0x5B };
    char key[] = { 0x40, 0x35, 0x20, 0x56 };
    char key1[] = { "flag" };
    char key2[5] = { 0 };
    char flag[26] = { 0};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        key2[i] ^=ida_chars[i]^ key1[i];
    }

    printf("%s\n", key2);
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
    {
        flag[j] = ida_chars[j] ^ key2[j % 4];

        printf("%c", flag[j]);
    }


   //out1:&YA1]烫烫烫烫烫蘤lag
//out2:flag{Act1ve_Defen5e_Test}
}
```

Why the output of the first code (demo1) is garbled and the output of the second code demo2 is correct?It seems to me that these two functions are obviously the same？I don't know where the error happened, maybe a stack overflow?Or something like a heap overflow？

Comment: `int len1 = strlen(key);` is a bug in the first code. `key` is not a null terminated c-string so you can't call strlen().

Comment: Is this code supposed to be C or C++?  `[![printf("%c", flag\[j\]);][1]][1]` is neither.

Comment: @DrewDormann: I'm guessing they accidentally hit the "add link" hotkey or something. They should correct it regardless, and clarify if the intent is to write C or C++ by removing the other tag.

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm sorry to make you see this error. Corrected errors

Comment: FYI, characters less than 0x20 are not printable (according to ASCII encoding).

Answer (score 2):

This one

```
char key2[5] = { 0 };
char flag[26] = { 0};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    key2[i] ^=ida_chars[i]^ key1[i];
}
```

fails because 'key2[4]' ends up not being 0.

You need

```
char key2[6] = { 0 }; <<<<=== ensure 0 always on the end of the string
char flag[26] = { 0};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    key2[i] ^= ida_chars[i] ^ key1[i];
}
```

A C [string](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1) must *always* have a 0 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This call of strlen

```
int len1 = strlen(key);
```

results in undefined behavior because the array key does not contain a string

```
char key[] = { 0x40, 0x35, 0x20, 0x56 };
```